# Fill color between 2 shape lines

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, shapes, fill

I've got two layers, a shape in each layer. What I want is to fill the lines between the two shapes. I've tried to merge the shapes but then it just stays completely filled in, like the screenshot.

I could bypass it by putting the first shape on top of the second and fill it with the same colour as the background, but I want it to be transparent.

[image]
[image]

I feel like this should be super easy but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Highlight both shape layers in the **Layers Panel** and 
  from the **Layer Panel Menu** choose `Merge Shapes`
  [image]
- You get a single shape layer that has your paths and no fill
  [image]
- In the **Control Bar** across the top of the screen, under the shape interaction item, choose `Exclude Overlapping Shapes`
  [image]
- Reapply the fill
  [image]

---

The order of these steps isn't overly important. You can set the path interaction to `Exclude` and *then* merge the shapes - same end result.

Comment: Incredible! I had seen that option and tried several things but apparently I did it wrong. Thanks a bunch!!!